# function for validating email addresses

Tags: php, email-address

I am using this function for validating email addresses,
but it doesn’t work if the email address is like this:

```
name@server.com. 
OR 
//name@server.com
```

Is there a way to develop this function?

```
function validEmail($email)
{
   $isValid = true;
   $atIndex = strrpos($email, "@");
   if (is_bool($atIndex) && !$atIndex)
   {
      $isValid = false;
   }
   else
   {
      $domain = substr($email, $atIndex+1);
      $local = substr($email, 0, $atIndex);
      $localLen = strlen($local);
      $domainLen = strlen($domain);
      if ($localLen < 1 || $localLen > 64)
      {
         // local part length exceeded
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if ($domainLen < 1 || $domainLen > 255)
      {
         // domain part length exceeded
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if ($local[0] == '.' || $local[$localLen-1] == '.')
      {
         // local part starts or ends with '.'
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $local))
      {
         // local part has two consecutive dots
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if (!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9\\-\\.]+$/', $domain))
      {
         // character not valid in domain part
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $domain))
      {
         // domain part has two consecutive dots
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if
(!preg_match('/^(\\\\.|[A-Za-z0-9!#%&`_=\\/$\'*+?^{}|~.-])+$/',
                 str_replace("\\\\","",$local)))
      {
         // character not valid in local part unless 
         // local part is quoted
         if (!preg_match('/^"(\\\\"|[^"])+"$/',
             str_replace("\\\\","",$local)))
         {
            $isValid = false;
         }
      }
      if ($isValid && !(checkdnsrr($domain,"MX") || checkdnsrr($domain,"A")))
      {
         // domain not found in DNS
         $isValid = false;
      }
   }
   return $isValid;
}
```

Comment: [How to validate eMails in PHP has been answered countless times before](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=validate+email+php). [PHP has a native filter function for this](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php).

Comment: There are many regular expressions that have been created to validate emails. Just google "email regex" and you will get a number of results.

Comment: you are right thx thou, i am checking filter function just now thx

Comment: Your `preg_match` on `$domain` is too restrictive - non-ASCII characters are allowed in domain names, for example `èéê.com` is a valid domain name. I also think the spec does not prohibit an initial or final dot, or consecutive dots, in the local part of the address.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if an email address exists without sending an email?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565504/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-exists-without-sending-an-email)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[filter_var()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)**. Below is a simple use demonstration. Many other options are available.

```
<?php

  // You might want to trim whitespace first: 
$possibleEmailAddress = trim($possibleEmailAddress);

filter_var($possibleEmailAddress, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

// Returns false if $possibleEmailAddress doesn't appear valid.
// Returns the email string if it does appear okay.
?>
```

**[live example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/dVLu2Y)**

Note that `//name@server.com` is a valid email, but `name@server.com.` is not. You'd have to trim the period from the end to make it valid. You can't just use `trim()`, since periods at the beginning of an email could be valid and intentional.

Answer (score -2):

```
function  checkEmail($email) 
    {
    $patern = '/^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/';
    if (preg_match($patern , $email)) 
        {
        return TRUE;
        }
    else
        { 
        return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

the simplest

Comment: and wrong. doesn't even account for + signs in the local part.

Comment: and rejects existing top level domains, like `.museum`

Answer (score -2):

Or, same as Asar's but shorter:

```
function  checkEmail($email) {
     $patern = '/^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/';
     return preg_match($patern , $email);
}
```

Comment: Rejects `.museum` domains etc., rejects one of my *actual* email addresses that has a `+` in it.

Comment: I just simplified Asar's code and regex; thanks everyone for voting down ><