# Is there a way to test if an E-Mail address exists without sending a test mail?

Tags: email, smtp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if an email address exists without sending an email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565504/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-exists-without-sending-an-email)

I am trying to find some way to test if an E-mail address actually exists without sending a test mail.

One can validate e-mail address but is not guaranteed if the address actually exists. like

```
abc@example.com
```

Is there a way to avoid this?

Thank you

Comment: In short, you can't.  Because even the domain exists, you can't guarantee the user/account does.

Comment: You can try a MX lookup on the domain to see if that at least exists, but as shinkou said that doesn't guarantee the user account exists

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer is no - the only way to validate it exists is to connect to the mail server and send an email to it.

Some more info : [Can I check if an email address exists using .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883518/can-i-check-if-an-email-address-exists-using-net)

"SMTP defines a command for this, but since abuse by spammers totally overwhelmed the number of legitimate uses, virtually every e-mail server in the world is configured to lie."

Another similar question : [How to check if an email address exists without sending an email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565504/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-exists-without-sending-an-email/566121#566121)