# how to check email id is exist or not in c# for all Domain

Tags: c#

I have sent email using SMTP. It doesn't check email id is exist or not, it just passes the email id to the mail server. If email ID not exists, Some mail delivery agents provide the reply service which tells you that the address is not available. Then only I can recognize that corresponding email is id not exist.

Is there any option to know sent email id is exist or not, Mail sent correctly or returned the error back like not valid.

Please share your view. Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Ramkumar. S

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if an email address is real or valid using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19261987/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-is-real-or-valid-using-php)

Comment: @KenY-N - that is PHP, this is clearly C#. You will need to setup the SMTP server: https://serverfault.com/questions/60678/e-mail-bounce-management

Comment: @JeremyThompson But it describes how and why it cannot be done, so I thought it was at least a starting point.

Comment: @KenY-N firstly it describes how it **CAN** be done but in PHP. If you dont know 100% if something can or cant be done best not to comment at all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because person asking the question did not try to find out email sending mechanism.

Comment: @JeremyThompson If it can be done in PHP, it can be done with other languages as well. Frankly, you can check the email format. When your SMTP sends mail, then the server can respond with Mail ID does not exist, and hence, bounce occurs. You should know the SMTP server name for every domain as per PHP solution. So, that can be solution which can be deployed for a company internally, not globally.

Comment: According to [Can I check if an email address exists using .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883518/can-i-check-if-an-email-address-exists-using-net), this cannot be done in a way that is reliable.

Comment: Not through SMTP.  SMTP is only for sending email.  Any response would be sent to the email account and you would have to login to the account and check for responses.