# PHP Script To Check If An Email Is Valid Without Sending Confirmation

Tags: php, email, smtp, email-validation

I've found a couple online services that do this, and I found this post at stackoverflow about it:

[How to check if an email address exists without sending an email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565504/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-exists-without-sending-an-email)

The problem is that the PHP script linked to there requires you to populate a list of nameservers and domains, and thus (I think) only works if you are validating emails on a known domain.  I want something that will work for any email (at least work with a high probability).  I found a script that does it that I can buy for $40, but I'd rather find the same thing as open source.

Thanks for any advice,
Jonah

Comment: You can't verify an email with 100% accuracy without sending a confirmation.

Comment: I concur. If the methods described in your link were supported generally, we would be in deep $!?^ since spammers can do the same with our email addies...

Comment: ummmm.... can someone tell me what happened to the other answer posted here by Christopher yesterday?   It appears to have been deleted.  Why would this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
$emailValidation = /(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])/;

if(preg_match($emailValidation, $testEmail)) {
    echo "valid email.";
} else {
    echo "invalid email.";
}
```

Is a well used email validation regex, which is PHP compatible.

Just check email addresses against it and you're done.

But note that without a confirmation postback you will **never** know that an email is 100% valid.

Comment: How the hell do you wrap that expression in quotes?

Comment: Shouldn't one at least request MX records from the domain to check if the mail is deliverable?

Comment: This answer although accepted, isn't doing what was asked.

Comment: You should post an answer if you have something useful to add