# How to Check in asp.net the Email Id exists or not in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to know that when user registering how to check the email id is exists or not.

Comment: What are you trying to do? seeing if you have that email in your database already or if the email is not only valid but a real one?

Comment: Dear friend i have all this i want to know that any user enter 123@gmail.com then the 123@gmail.com exits on the gmail server or not it may happen with any server. I want to know that

Comment: Then your question should be **How can I validate an email in order to know if it's an existing and used email**, and not using "Email id" that is general referencing a Database! You get the answered based on the type of question you put here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how check a validated Email Exist Or Not Without Sending test Email by c# codes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246341/how-check-a-validated-email-exist-or-not-without-sending-test-email-by-c-codes)

Answer (score 0):

In order to validate an email you can use 2 things

- Send yourself an email and check the answer back (this can take up to 24 hours as email servers sometimes don't send the answer back right away) and read the response headers back from the email server
- You can signup for a commercial service that does this for you.

**BUT**

## We never, ever, do this ...

We simply send the user an email with a confirmation link and block his/her account until they confirm it.

for example:

The user `bruno` creates an account in your website with the email `abc@domain.com`.
After you create the user in your `User` table you also have a `bit` (boolean) `column` names `is_confirmed` that you say `0`

```
DECLARE @guid uniqueidentifier 
SET @guid = NEWID();


INSERT INTO [TblUsers]
    ( 'email', 'username', 'is_confirmed', 'create_date', 'unique_id' )
VALUES
    ( 'abc@domain.com', 'bruno', 0, GETDATE(), @guid );

SELECT @guid;
```

then you send a nice Welcome email with the id you got form the insert procedure

```
http://yourdomain.com/confirm/?<%= userGuid %>
```

you simple send a Welcome message asking the user to confirm within that link, open confirm, welcome him and ask to provide a password.

That's how we see if the email is a real one or not!

Comment: ya i know that and i had done it but i want to is their any way to validate the user other than sending a link of activation. Bcz their are more than 10000 registration per day on my site if their are large amount of fake emailid and i want to reduce the size of data base that is why i am asking this sir

Comment: As I said, use a commercial service for this or send the email and get the received `header`.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to know whether they have entered a genuine, real email address that they use, then the only way is to send them something then have them confirm it back to you.

If you just want to check the format is valid, then Google (or Bing if that is your preference) for `email address verification regular expression`.