# How to check email address exists or not using ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

How to check the given email (any valid email) address exists or not using ASP.NET?

Comment: Are you talking syntax or whether it actually exists? In the latter case, you can't; It will simply bounce back. Check similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246341/how-check-a-validated-email-exist-or-not-without-sending-test-email-by-c-sharp-c

Comment: What do you believe it means for an email address to 'exist' ?

Comment: http://lamsonproject.org/blog/2009-07-09.html

Comment: Possible Duplicate **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565504/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-exists-without-sending-an-email**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't check if an email exists without actually sending an mail.

The only thing you can check is if the address is in a correct shape with regexes:

```
string email = txtemail.Text;
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$");
Match match = regex.Match(email);
if (match.Success)
    Response.Write(email + " is corrct");
else
    Response.Write(email + " is incorrct");
```

Comment: This is just checking for valid email **FORMAT** !!!. Every email that has a proper format may not exist

Answer (score 1):

```
you send invitation mail to user with encrypted key..
If user is verified you have to verified key and you have only verified email..
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code solution that may work for you. This sample sends a message from address different from From: address specified in the message. This is useful when bounced messages should be processed and the developer wants to redirect bounced messages to another address.

http://www.afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/docs/MailBee.SmtpMail.Smtp.Send_overload_3.html

Answer (score 0):

The full process is not so simple.
Its required a full communication with the email server and ask him if this email exist or not.

I know a vendor that give a dll that make all this communication and check if the email exist or not on the server, the aspNetMX at http://www.advancedintellect.com/product.aspx?mx

Answer (score 0):

First you need to import this namespace:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

private bool ValidateEmail(string email)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$");
    Match match = regex.Match(email);
    if (match.Success)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

[Visit Here](http://www.stepover-f10.com/2014/01/validate-email-address-in-csharp.aspx) to full source code.