# Validating email address domain in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, email

I want to create a web application using any technology that accepts an email address and checks if the domain of the email address exists. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the C# code to check domain from email Id

```
var domain = emailaddress.Split('@')[1];
var server = Dns.Resolve(domain);
```

Comment: What i thought of doing is create a aspx page with the textbox, label and a button. On the click of the button the email address have to be checked. this I thought could be done with an if statement. and if the domain exists an alert would be displayed. Is my idea right? Can we do it this way? if yes, how do we split the address and execute the if statement?? Plz advice.

Comment: Thanks madhu, but how could we split the array? The if statement would resemble something like if(username.text=________) then alert('domain name valid') else alert('domain name invalid')

Comment: may be link below will be useful for u
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873118/checking-if-an-email-address-exists