# MVC 5 Identity 2.0 Email Confirmation/Activation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, identity

I currently have a MVC 5 project upgraded from Identity 1.0 to Identiy 2.0, but would like to take advantage of a few things.

Firstly login with Email instead of UserName, secondly extend the standard registration with email confirmation and activation.

Can someone please provide an example of how to modify the previous v1.0 implantation to v2.0 solution?

Any help would be very much appreciated :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295236/email-confirmation-with-mvc-5-and-asp-net-identity?rq=1

Comment: This suggestion is for Identity 1.0, Identity 2.0 was released March this year, thank you though.