# Error in sending mail from server smtp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, email, smtp

My mail sending code is as follows which has been hosted on the server:

```
try
    {
        MailMessage msgMail = new MailMessage();

        MailMessage myMessage = new MailMessage();
        myMessage.From = new MailAddress("*****");
        myMessage.To.Add(TextBox1.Text);
        myMessage.Subject = "Subject";
        myMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

        myMessage.Body = "Message Body";


        SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        System.Net.NetworkCredential myCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("email", "password");
        mySmtpClient.Host = "****";  //Have specified the smtp host name
        mySmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        mySmtpClient.Credentials = myCredential;


        mySmtpClient.Send(myMessage);
        myMessage.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.ToString());
    }
```

I keep on getting this error

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: #5.1.0 Address rejected abc@yahoo.com at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) at Mail.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\hosting\9110120\html\FB\Mail.aspx.cs:line 37
```

I have tried everything.It keeps giving the same error

My site is hosted on Godaddy server

Comment: Is the address you are sending to a valid e-mail account?  Some servers will reject mail immediately if the recipient is unknown.

Comment: yes i am specifying a valid email address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems fine, apparently it could be that you need to configure it:  http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5444

Comment: When i am sending an email to myself on the server i receive it

Comment: There maybe an issue with outgoing e-mails? If the e-mail works fine to yourself on the same server that would indicate your code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's failing because the email address doesn't exist. Just handle the exception and you should be all set.

[How to check if an email address exists without sending an email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565504/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-exists-without-sending-an-email)

Comment: The email i am actually specifying is correct this is just an example

Comment: its an email address either gmail or yahoo and what do you mean inside a network?

Comment: I think GoDaddy has a standard host for SMTP emails. What host are you using? And are you using the same credentials for logging into GoDaddy?

Comment: i have tried with both smtpout.secureserver.net and relay-hosting.secureserver.net ...... No i am not using the same credentials i have created an email address and password as was specified in Godaddy

Comment: Try using the email address and password you use to login to Godaddy as the credentials. I had a similar issue before, and I think it had something to do with that.

Comment: I have solved my problem ! My stupid mistake thanks for helping !

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem , fixed it by a small change in the line below

System.Net.NetworkCredential myCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("email", "password");

verify your credentials , that worked for me :) ..