# How can I check if an email address is Correct and Exists?

Tags: email, smtp, telnet, email-verification

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if an email address exists without sending an email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565504/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-exists-without-sending-an-email)

I was wondering : is there a way to check if an email address is *Correct* and it *Exists* before sending an email, using *Telnet* or *SMTP Protocol cmd-line* ?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for.

http://www.webdigi.co.uk/blog/2009/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-exists-without-sending-an-email/

Answer (score 1):

The only valid solution to detect if an email address exists is to send an email and wait for answer.

Most of the times you also want to be sure that your user is the owner of the account, and this solution does both checks.

You can't do this client-side only, you'll need a server-side API.