# How to disable postfix address verification

Tags: email, smtp, postfix-mta

I'm doing some spam/botnet research and need to accept all email that my mail server receives.  I've set postfix up, but I can't seem to figure out how to disable the sender address verification function.  During my initial tests (spoofing mail source as test@test.com), I discovered postfix checks with the sender's mail server to verify the user exists (which it doesn't in my test case).  As a result, the test message fails.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it...
Paste this in /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
smtpd_restriction_classes = verify_sender
verify_sender = permit
```