# Mailbox existence checking

Tags: php

How to Performs deep level SMTP verification on each email address, each email address will be verified for mailbox existence without sending actual emails on that address in **PHP**?

suppose i have 5 email address

```
abc@gmail.com
def@gmail.com (fake)
ghi@gmail.com
jkl@gmail.com (fake)
mno@gmail.com
```

from above list, i have 2 fake/Spam email-id, i want to filter email-id by real and fake/Spam emails without sending email?

Comment: Give better example.

Comment: Your question shows [no attempt](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) of solving the problem. If you try, you may succeed. But if you do not, you will always fail. And if you did try, without sharing our efforts with others, they may duplicate your work instead of providing a working solution.

Comment: Can't be done. To verify an email address actually exists you need to send an email to it and wait for a response. The response may not always be valid i.e. mailbox full or other tech issue. All php, and other languages, can do is check that the email address mets certain criteria.

Comment: @savshit you need to use any email validate API to verify the email address before sending mail

Comment: I add example what i mean to do with PHP.

Comment: Adding to what @jeff said, this would pose a huge problem. If spam bots were able to identify every single gmail address like this, our inboxes would soon be filled with more spam than actual emails.

Comment: Even if you can tell existing from non-existing addresses, the fact that an address *exists* still doesn't mean any particular human will receive/see emails you send to it. That's yet another layer. If you want to ensure you can communicate with a particular human via email, the only way is to send them an email and have them click a link/type a confirmation code or some such feedback loop.

Comment: Use API's that provides details for email verified and you can mark your DB with valid/invalid e-mail and send mails accordingly. - [https://mailboxlayer.com/](https://mailboxlayer.com/ ) - [http://emailpie.com/](http://emailpie.com/)

Comment: @ZuberSurya It really depends on how those services work, because if they check with SMTP then they won't work properly (see my answer).

Comment: @SavshitMavani Did my answer help you? If so, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

[You can](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19263515/2422013):

> You should check with SMTP.
>
> That means you have to connect to that email's SMTP server.
>
> After connecting to the SMTP server you should send these commands:
>
> HELO somehostname.com MAIL FROM:  RCPT TO:
>    If you get ":
>   Relay access denied" that means this email in invalid.
>
> There is a simple PHP class. You can use it:
>
> http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6650-PHP-Check-if-an-e-mail-is-valid-using-SMTP.html

...but it isn't advisable:

> This is technically true, but practically inadvisable: ISPs (especially
>   Yahoo and Hotmail) know about this and they will block deliveries from
>   you (even to addresses that do exist) if you do this a lot. In short,
>   don't do it.

If you're looking to verify an email address the best choice is to send an email and then monitor for any bounces- I myself use AWS SES which gives a response to whether sending was a success. You can find the [AWS PHP SDK here](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/).

If you want to use AWS SES, be aware that there is an approval process you need to go through until they'll allow you to send email to anyone.