# I was working in a application in which i need to verify email id that its existing or not

Tags: php

So, the thing is I was working on the application in which I need to check that the email id is currently active or in working state or not, for which I used `fsockopen()` function of PHP, now what happens is in my localhost XAMPP its working fine but when I uploaded it to the server bigrock it is giving an error as:

> Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com:465 (Connection timed out)

My code is.

```
function email_validation($email){
    list($name, $domain)=explode('@',$email);
    $max_conn_time = 30;
    $sock='';
    $port = 25;
    $max_read_time = 5;
    $users=$name;
    $hosts = array();
    $mxweights = array();
    getmxrr($domain, $hosts, $mxweights);
    $mxs = array_combine($hosts, $mxweights);
    asort($mxs, SORT_NUMERIC);
    $mxs[$domain] = 100;
    $timeout = $max_conn_time / count($mxs);
        while(list($host) = each($mxs)){
        $host="ssl://".$host;
        if($sock = fsockopen($host, 465, $errno, $errstr, 10)){
        stream_set_timeout($sock, $max_read_time);
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any help will be more than sufficient for me.

Comment: You sure about that protocol? `ssl://gmail...` ?

Comment: As an aside - the only way you can *really* know whether an email exists or not is to email it. All `getmxrr()` will tell you is whether the receiving domain is configured to receive emails. You should probably also [check that the email is of a valid format](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php) before looking up the MX record on the domain.

Comment: @CD001 is there any other way through which i can check whether email id is existing or not in php.

Comment: Yes - but it's not normally necessary, or even a good idea - checking the format of the email and the MX record on the domain is enough: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19261987/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-is-real-or-valid-using-php - if you need to verify the email address fully you should send an email to that address with a verification link in it.

Comment: ok thank you, it means that their is no need of using fsockopen() in the code , only with the help of checkdnsrr() and getmxrr() i can verify the email id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this by parsing the domain of the email:

```
if(checkdnsrr(array_pop(explode("@",$email)),"MX")) {
     // valid email    
}
```

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdnsrr.php

Comment: That's actually pretty much what's being done - it'll be a bit more obvious once the edit to the OP has been approved.

Comment: @CD001 Yes. Currently, it's all messy and ambiguous.

Comment: @Amit Merchant thanks for the reply, so as off now can you tell me any other way through i can tell that email id is existing or not in php