# It's showing mail is sent

Tags: codeigniter, email

```
$this->email->to($this->session->userdata('email1'));
$this->email->subject('Hall-book');
$this->email->message(''.$message['uname'].'');
if ($this->email->send()) {
    log_message("info","mail sent");
} else {
    log_message("info","mail not sent");
}
```

If my email, suppose `email1`, is wrong email. It should not send the email, else part should be executed, but it's showing the message sent. Please help me for this.

Comment: Define "wrong e-mail... if you just made a typo like `@gmial.com`, the mail will be sent, I don't think this is a good way to test for error...

Comment: No,Actually I have sent some thing hjhjhhuhuhj@gmail.com then also its showing "the mail has sent "!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whether you have given a wrong email id or not, it should send the mail with the specified Id. it will not check for a valid email id(it will not ensure succesfull email delivery). So "if($this->email->send())"  always return true. thats why, u r getting sent message. I hope u will change your error checking method.

My suggetion,

either add a try catch block to catch the run time error(it won't solve valid email id problem) or do a email validation before send.

Comment: Thanks,For correct email id it will send the mail. I think I need to do the verification of that mail id before sending.

Answer (score 0):

This function is send mail only. when mail is send then $this->mail->send(); return true.
For check the email id you should write a different block of code if mail is correct then this function is called otherwise return false.

Comment: like what type of different **block of code ** need to be added .For verification email

Comment: For it should be proper mail(mail validation) id user regular expression . and then write code.

Comment: Thank you . But Actually I  wanted to know without sending any email to that client,how to know whether that email Id exists or not ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565504/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-exists-without-sending-an-email