# Node.js Email existence Check

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to make sure a user types in a valid email that also actually exists, not just valid in format. There is a npm package called email-existence that should do this but every email returns a false so that is not reliable. If there is a javascript/Node.js Package that does this job, it would be great, but is there also a way I can do this myself? Like ways to create a small module for this functionality?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only guaranteed way to find out whether an e-mail address exists is to send an e-mail to it - this is why verification e-mails exist.

There's a similar discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565504/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-exists-without-sending-an-email) with a few answers detailing possible ways to try and determine if an address exists on a server, but none are guaranteed to work on every server.

Alternatively, you could use a paid service such as [Kickbox.io](http://kickbox.io/) (they also have a 100/day free quota), which claims to verify that an e-mail address exists as well as determine the "quality" (based on deliverability and other metrics) of an address. Kickbox has a [node.js package](https://github.com/kickboxio/kickbox-node).

Comment: In SMTP the process of sending an e-mail is preceded by `MAIL FROM` and `RCPT TO` commands. The SMTP server will, for instance, respond with `550-5.1.1` if the mailbox does not exist. Here is a screenshot that I have taken of this functionality on Gmail's SMTP: https://i.ibb.co/hKdTWZZ/image.png

Answer (score 4):

Installation
To install via npm:

```
npm install email-existence
```

Usage

Check existence:

```
emailExistence.check('email@domain.com', function(err,res){
    console.log('res: '+res);
});
```

Comment: I found this one not validating yahoo, even though the email id doesn't exits, it returns true

Comment: This package doesn't seem to work too well. Validates some gmail addresses. but most corporate emails it can't seem to validate.

Comment: Prints true of false for any mailbox independent if it really exists on the particular server

Comment: returning `"res: false"` for all emails, either exting or not. may be it's no longer working.

Answer (score 0):

I think "email-verifier" package will come handy in this case

Source : https://medium.com/whois-api/how-to-verify-an-email-address-using-node-js-449330a47a7e

Comment: This is working for yahoo, outlook, hotmail and gmail