# Checking existence of email address

Tags: php, jquery, asp.net, validation, email

I'm developing a web application with Chat Support, and so far, I've been using JQuery validation to check whether the input text is a well formatted email address.

But that doesn't seem to fulfill its purpose.

**For example:**

1. Entering a working and legitimate email address such as
   ***myname@gmail.com***
2. Entering a fake/random email address such as ***abcd@something.com***

Both are accepted into the field as valid.

So is there any way to detect whether the specified email address exists or not in real-life, by using PHP (or any other) without sending the user, a `click-to-confirm` email?

I've tried the SMTP method discussed in the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565504/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-exists-without-sending-an-email), but unfortunately, the server returned error for all Email addresses, even legitimate ones. I think they have prevented enumeration for security purposes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if an email address exists without sending an email?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565504/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-exists-without-sending-an-email)

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/224020

Comment: If there were a reliable way for anyone to check whether an email address exists, that would make the lives of spammers very easy indeed. Ask yourself instead *why* having a valid email at that point is so critical, and ways to address that specific need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to reliably check if email address actually exists withotu sending an actual email. All you can do by yourself is to check syntax of email address and check of domain name exists.

To check email address syntax:

```
filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
```

To check A and MX records:

```
checkdnsrr($domain,"MX") || checkdnsrr($domain,"A")
```

Next step is to send actual email with confirmation URL or confirmation code.

Comment: Yes, so far I've been sending _confirmation URL_ type email, but the user's doesn't seem to like it that much, since every time they need to start a chat, they need to wait for mail, and verify, which is somewhat like inconvenience.

Comment: @SnazzySanoj yes, it's an inconvenience but there isn't real way around it. Also, every user should do this only one time per each unique email address.