# Check if an email address exists - ColdFusion

Tags: email, coldfusion, smtp

I am trying to figure out a way to check if an email address exists without sending out an email. Anyone did something like this before in ColdFusion?

Comment: [mailboxlayer.com](https://mailboxlayer.com/) offers a REST API for validating email addresses.

Comment: Did you search the archives first? There is nothing built into CF, but there are possible options such as [online mail verification services OR issuing low level commands to the mail server via telnet, etcetera](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565504/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-exists-without-sending-an-email). None of them are 100%, but are as good as it gets AFAIK.

Comment: We use the Java isEmail class from http://isemail.info/ (no longer available). It performs a cached background MX check to determine if the mail domain is valid, but I don't think there's any way to verify whether it truly exists. Many mail servers will accept incoming bad email w/o revealing existence, process it and then bounce or delete it to protect against directory harvest attacks (DHA).

Comment: @AlE. Thanks!!! It works great!

Comment: One possible solution that may be easier to implement is to just make users verify their email address first.  Then only send emails with a verified address.