# Laravel email validation with domain name twice

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5

I have the following validation rules in controller for email validation. But it takes domain name twice or more like **something@gmail.com.com**

```
  $rules = [
 'email' => 'required|email|unique:users'
   ];
 $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }
```

My form.blade.php is

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="">Email </label>
 <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Enter mail ID"/>
</div>
```

I want to restrict domain name to one like **something@gmail.com** not **something@gmail.com.com**

Thanks

Comment: This is odd. Can you post some more part of your code, perhaps the form?

Comment: I have edited my question, thanks

Comment: @BugzillaTest you can check user has provided a valid url or not user might have an email @ gmail.com.com

Comment: how i can be sure is that valid or not?

Comment: ccTLDs can have two dots, for example, user@company.co.uk

Comment: so how to be sure of valid email?

Comment: If an email has an @ sign, as well as at least 1 dot, then the only way to be sure whether the email is valid or not is by sending an email to it.

Answer (score 1):

Please sent verification email after complete necessary validation in JS and PHP.

Comment: currently i am doing it after saving data to database. But is there anyway to validate the existent of email before save to database?

Comment: please follow this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565504/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-exists-without-sending-an-email

Comment: Get the domain name of that email. 
like something@gmail.com here domain name is gmail.com
Then sent a request to www.gmail.com if response code is 200 then domain exists and that means email address is valid.