# How to validate provided email address?

Tags: python, django, email, smtp

I am creating a website in Django, using django-registration-redux. I send the registration activation code to the user's email address.  If the email is invalid, my website still works, but it GMail gives me a error that the address does not exist.
I want my web site to validate the address, giving this for an invalid one:

> "email doesn't exist".

How can I do this?  My on-line searches have turned up nothing.

Comment: `but if the email is wrong website still works` what do you mean by this ?

Comment: like if i give email :abc@gmail.com  it will proceed to new page but when it tries to send mail to abc@gmail.com it gives me an error on gmail but not on my website.

Comment: Yes. It will only give error only on your gmail. AFAIK there is no way to check whether an email is valid, unless the mail providers themselves expose an API to do so....I know none such API...Even if there is such an API, the solution would not be generic

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565504/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-exists-without-sending-an-email

Comment: https://kickbox.io

Comment: how does kickbox works?

Comment: Send registration confirmation link  to target email. Later accept as a member(`if is valid`) ! Can't accept with 1 step ! Like: stackoverflow !

Comment: thanks it worked for me!!!

Comment: Corrected grammar and sentence flow.