# How to identify email without orignal envelop id

Tags: .net-core, office365, mailkit

I am using Office 365 as email server.

I have already checked my server supports Dsn

I have implemented code in given in example.

Problem is that "Original-Envelope-Id" is always null.

I am sending unique Message id while sending through mailkit smtp client and receiving through imap client.

Is there some alternative to check message id of delivery notification email.

Like sending some headers which I can receive in delivery email.

[ASP.NET MailKit SMTP response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48118781/asp-net-mailkit-smtp-response)

Comment: Can you provide a sample delivery status notification email that has a null Original-Envelope-Id? There are, afaik, no other headers that you can check or set.

Comment: I have emailed you email logs of smtp and imap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the delivery agent in your case decided to attach a `text/rfc822-headers` MIME part to the message instead of specifying the `Original-Envelope-Id` in the `message/delivery-status` MIME part content.

What you need to do is locate the [TextRfc822Headers](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MimeKit_TextRfc822Headers.htm) mime part and then check the `headers.Message.MessageId` property instead.