# How are emails verified for existance?

Tags: email, email-verification

I am building a webservice and are stuck with the validation of email addresses. Besides the typical Regular-expression verification, I also saw a few services validating an email address if they really exist.

For me the domain resolving makes sense, and to check if a MX entry is present in the DNS records, but how do they go beyond and check if the actual recipient exists?

Services for instance like these: https://emailverification.whoisxmlapi.com/api

How do they technically do this? I have my own webserver and it got it right. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you buy email addresses in bulk to build a spam list, forget it. If people sign up for your newsletter or something else, send them a confirmation email (that is the verification). You may want to look into GDPR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking MX records is a first step. After that, you connect to the SMTP server at the addresses given by these records. Then:

1. You can send a `RCPT TO: <mail_to_check>` command, and see if the response of the SMTP server.

   - If the user exists, you'll get a `250 2.1.5 Recipient OK`.
   - Or else, you'll get a `5.1.1 DSN`.
2. You can send a `VRFY <mail_to_check>` command, however, per my experience, very few servers support this command.

#### Caveats

Please note that this method **does not work** 100% of the time. Here are some potential issues:

- some servers just plainly disable this feature, to avoid bots listing through their users.
- greylisting: some servers block 1st connection from an unknown IP, and allow subsequent ones.
- be aware of catch-call providers, which accept `*@mydomain.com`, but doesn't necessarily mean that the inbox actually belongs to someone.
- and if you send too many requests to one server from the same IP, there's a high chance this IP will get blacklisted.

#### Example Demo

Below is the output of such a flow taken from [another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565504/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-exists-without-sending-an-email#answer-4478832). It finds the MX records of `stackoverflow.com`, and uses telnet to connect to the SMTP server and send/parse SMTP commands.

```
C:\>nslookup -q=mx stackoverflow.com
Non-authoritative answer:
stackoverflow.com       MX preference = 40, mail exchanger = STACKOVERFLOW.COM.S9B2.PSMTP.com
stackoverflow.com       MX preference = 10, mail exchanger = STACKOVERFLOW.COM.S9A1.PSMTP.com
stackoverflow.com       MX preference = 20, mail exchanger = STACKOVERFLOW.COM.S9A2.PSMTP.com
stackoverflow.com       MX preference = 30, mail exchanger = STACKOVERFLOW.COM.S9B1.PSMTP.com

C:\>telnet STACKOVERFLOW.COM.S9A1.PSMTP.com 25
220 Postini ESMTP 213 y6_35_0c4 ready.  CA Business and Professions Code Section 17538.45 forbids use of this system for unsolicited electronic mail advertisements.

helo hi
250 Postini says hello back

mail from: <me@myhost.com>
250 Ok

rcpt to: <fake@stackoverflow.com>
550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try
550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or
550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at
550 5.1.1 http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=6596 w41si3198459wfd.71
```

#### Disclosure

I run [Reacher](https://reacher.email), a real-time email verification API. My code is written in Rust, and is 100% open-source. Check it out if you want a more robust solution:

https://github.com/amaurymartiny/check-if-email-exists

Jumping through some hoops to overcome the above caveats, I manage to verify **around 80% of the emails** my customers check.