# Method Verify mailkit

Tags: c#, mailkit

How to run Verify the existence of a mailbox address.?

http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/M_MailKit_Net_Smtp_SmtpClient_Verify.htm

```
using (var client = new SmtpClient())
    {
        
        client.Connect("smtp.mail.ru", 465, true);

        client.Authenticate(name, pass);

        var d = client.Verify(email);

       
    }
```

Error MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpCommandException: "unrecognized command"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if an email address exists without sending an email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565504/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-exists-without-sending-an-email)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most SMTP servers do not support the VRFY command anymore. Your server doesn't support it which is why you are getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

Possible a duplicate.
You can read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565504/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-exists-without-sending-an-email), it's in `PHP` but all the concepts are the same for your situation.

As jstedfast said, that command isn't supported anymore and to sum up your reading: There is not a reliable way to verify that anymore because of spams.