# How to find smtp sendmail response

Tags: python, smtp, slamdata

**Is that possible to get a response from following method. Either any way to see to_email is a valid one**

smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)

Comment: I didn't test it but how about `response = smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)` ? But I'm not sure if it doesn't raise error when `to_email` is wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure if SMTP sends response directly - it may try to send this mail few times with some delays (somethimes few hours) and when it will not work then it may send back mail to `from_addr`

Comment: [How to check if an email address exists without sending an email? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565504/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-exists-without-sending-an-email)